# Xamarin.Forms: debugger stops at GetPositionAsync()?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to retrieve the coordinates of my location, but the debugger never moves beyond `var myPosition = await locator.GetPositionAsync();`. The debugger never hits the lines where floats `lat` and `lon` are assigned values.

I don't receive an error, it just hangs and the only way to cancel is to stop debugging. Here's the code:

```
private static async Task<string> GetPosition()
{
    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
    locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
    var myPosition = await locator.GetPositionAsync();
    float lat = myPosition.Latitude;
    float lon = myPosition.Longitude;
    return string.Empty; 
}

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var position = GetPosition().Result;
    //Everything else
}
```

Why doesn't the debugger move past `var myPosition = await locator.GetPositionAsync();`? I assume it has to do with the async `await` call, but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried `var myPosition = await locator.GetPositionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` because it solved a similar issie, but the debugger still doesn't move beyond `GetPositionAsync`.

Comment: I edited the title because this is not called 'debugger hangs', debugger works perfectly. If you don't like the new title edit it further.

Comment: I ended up using Savindya A's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47284058/4191466