# Not Getting Current Location in Tizen .Net Application

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tizen, xamarin.tizen

I am trying to [get location](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/.net-application/location-and-sensors/location-information) from the [`Tizen.Location.Locator`](https://samsung.github.io/TizenFX/latest/api/Tizen.Location.Locator.html) using the `GetLocation` method but I'm getting the values of latitude and longitude set to `0`.

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2017
- Emulator of Wearable 4.0
- Have already granted the [privileges](https://www.tizen.org/tv/privilege) for using location, also added the location feature in the manifest file.

Here's my code:

```
private static Locator locator = new Locator(LocationType.Gps);
try
{
    if (locator != null)
    {
        // Starts the Locator
        locator.Start();

        //Get Location
        Tizen.Location.Location currentLocation = locator.GetLocation();

        //Update xaml view
        latitudeValue.Text = currentLocation.Latitude.ToString();
        longitudeValue.Text = currentLocation.Longitude.ToString();
    }   
}
catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
{
    // Exception handling here
}
```

there's no description available about the variable `currentLocation` since it is being treated as a `bool` there. When I try to get the description by the quick watch feature of Visual Studio (by pressing `Shift + F9`), I get another error related to conversion of that bool variable

> member reference base type 'bool' is not a structure or union

The above code is not showing any `ServiceStateChanged` event registered, but I've also included that using the way shown in the [sample code](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/.net-application/location-and-sensors/location-information#start), but it didn't work for me.

Now wondering about what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Emulator emulates location. Have You changed to desired location in emulator's control panel? If not configured it will return 0,0

Comment: I really forgot about it .. thanks a lot for making my day :) Now it's working in emulator but it's giving the mock values on real device as well (as I set the mock values using `locator.SetMockLocation()` method) when **I removed the mocking** and started debugging, it threw **an exception on `locator.Start()` method**. Unfortunately I'm unable to see the description of the exception here.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPS most of time inactive because of battery consumption or Get location via Service provider

or

Use this Plugin to Get Current Location - https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin

```
 public async Task<Position> GetCurrentLocation()
{
   public static async Task<Position> GetCurrentPosition()
    {
            Position position = null;
            try
            {
                    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                    locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;

                    position = await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

                    if (position != null)
                    {
                            //got a cahched position, so let's use it.
                            return position;
                    }

                    if (!locator.IsGeolocationAvailable || !locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
                    {
                            //not available or enabled
                            return null;
                    }

                    position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), null, true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get location: " + ex);
            }

            if (position == null)
                    return null;

            var output = string.Format("Time: {0} \nLat: {1} \nLong: {2} \nAltitude: {3} \nAltitude Accuracy: {4} \nAccuracy: {5} \nHeading: {6} \nSpeed: {7}",
                    position.Timestamp, position.Latitude, position.Longitude,
                    position.Altitude, position.AltitudeAccuracy, position.Accuracy, position.Heading, position.Speed);

            Debug.WriteLine(output);

            return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to see an alternate way of doing this. I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763540/crossgeolocators-getpositionasync-does-not-work/41768952#41768952) way combined with your `if-else` condition. My code looks like [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/305601#Comment_305601) but I'm getting an exception, when I check the value of `CrossGeolocator.IsSupported` or `locator.IsGeolocationAvailable` or even `var position`, I get an error in quick watch about the _undeclared identifier_ over, am I missing any reference to use `CrossGeolocator` properly ?

Comment: Alternatively get location in local service provider